# Top level window focus/blur events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a simple frameset like

```
<frameset  rows="100, 200">
    <FRAME name="listener" src="frame1.html">
    <FRAME name="content" src="http://www.someexternalurl.com/">
 </frameset>
```

In the listener form trying to listen to the top window focus / blur:

```
<body>

<div id="szamlalo">30</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var inFocus = true;
var counter = 30;
var timer;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window.top).focus(function(){
    //$(window.top).focusin(function(){
        inFocus = true;
    });
    $(window.top).blur(function(){
    //$(window.top).focusout(function(){
        inFocus = false;
    });
    timer = window.setInterval("countdown()",1000);
});
function countdown()
{
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        if (inFocus)
            counter--;
    }
    else
    {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        window.location.href='masik_oldal.html';
    }
    $('#szamlalo').html(counter);
}
</script>
```

But aparently the major browsers all handles this differently, opera is the only one it works as expected. In IE the blur isn't received at all, chrome and firefox receive it only once...is this simply the different js engine implementation, or something in jquery? Or i made a mistake somewhere?
Thanks for any idea

Comment: Why frames? They are separate documents, so this can be tricky. You could probably achieve the same using one document.

Answer (score 0):

Events do not bubble up the frameset tree. You need to install separate handlers for each window (frame)